# Ionic livereload white screen

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

For several days I am trying to make work device live reloading.

I have forked [Ionic conference app](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app) and in order to use Auth0 SDK changed `architect:build` to use `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser` instead of `@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser`.

This is current [angular.json](https://gist.github.com/mareksip/773a4a4726b7fec5e5ffdf2d47c8593c) and custom [webpack.config.js](https://gist.github.com/mareksip/719e51ed9362f798b9c05dcab885944f)

I enabled port 8100 in firewall (also turned off firewall completely) so when I open Chrome on the Android device and navigate to 192.168.51.28:8100 I can see the app.

Commands:
1) ionic serve
- Serves to localhost:8100 and I can see the app in Chrome.

2) ionic cordova run android  --livereload-url=http://192.168.51.28:8100  --livereload 
- This changes config.xml :
- `<content src="index.html" />` to 
- adds `<allow-navigation href="http://192.168.51.28:8100" sessionid="278685e5" />`
- config.xml: https://gist.github.com/mareksip/8945fc3380a1972f3fb9c322bfc3d81d 
- Deploys and runs the app, later I can see splashscreen, loading circle and then only whitescreen. 
Output of console: https://gist.github.com/mareksip/666fc0dd946420166dc7a05d039b3b1a

Coud you please help me out of the white screen? :grinning:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the `tsconfig.json` and make sure in `compilerOptions` the `target` is set to `es5`

Comment: Changing `"target": "es2015"` to `"target": "es5"` helped resolve the issue!

Comment: I have the same problem, but the target is already set to `es5`